# Windows Startup and Logon scripts proper permissions

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

I'd like to know what the appropriate permissions should be for Startup and Logon scripts that run for everyone. Should Startup scripts have System read and execute permissions and Logon scripts read and execute for Authenticated Users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean what permission accounts should have toward your scripts, then it sounds right. Startup script is run under local system's context, while logon script is run under current user's context.